# Style resource inside subfolder of value

Tags: android, styles, directory

In my android project, inside `value` folder I created a folder called `appTheme` and inside this folder I have a style called "AppTheme" inside a file called `themes_apptheme.xml`. 
But when I try to access it using `@style/AppTheme` it just not work:

**`No resource find that matches the give name '@style/AppTheme'.`**

But when I move this file to `value` folder, it works.

The question is: How to referentiate the file on `appTheme` folder?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't crease subFolder in res folder !

Answer (score 1):

The android only uses one folder for each xml, now on your situation you are creating a folder inside the values folder which wont really work. `@style` will actually call the style name. calling the folder name next to it will not even call it but it is just an extra folder in the `values folder` with no use.

Have a look at [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html)

What you can see in there are only valid `xml and folder` in android.

and states:

```
They contain things such as application source code and resource files.
Some are generated for you by default, while others should be created if required
```

The `should be created if required` means the **folder** or **xml** that it is not generated upon creating the project like `anim` folder for animation.